# Regarding Maven Versions Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, version

I am trying to use a Maven Versions Plugin to upgrade all the child POM's to parent version and execute the build of all child modules in the parent pom.The Pom Files look like this

### Parent POM

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.build.pom</groupId>
    <artifactId>basepom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>
            <module>../Common</module>
        <module>
    <modules>

    <!-- . . . -->
</project>
```

### Child Pom

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>basepom</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.build.pom</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.child.common</groupId>
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Common</name>
<description>Common Jar</description>
```

Now if I run a Maven build on the base POM using the command from Eclipse

```
mvn clean install
```

The child module is getting build properly however if I update the basepom version to 2.0 and use version plugin command

```
mvn clean -N versions:update-child-modules install
```

The versions are getting updated however the child modules are not getting built.  Only the base pom gets build.

Do I have to explicitly specify to build the child modules in some Phase? What am I missing?.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the version of the parent manually you can use the set-goal like this:

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=XXX -DgenerateBackupPoms=false install
```

This updates the version of the parent and all childs and should execute the install afterwards.

---

**EDIT:**

To move parameters and execution to the pom, try sth like this (not tested):

```
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-versions-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <goals>
      <goal>set</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
       <newVersion>XXX</newVersion>
       <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

(If the version doesn't change the set goal should be ignored.)

Comment: Rob i don't want to update the MVN command each time. I use jenkins to Build the Wars and that the build is handled by a different team who don't have an idea on the version of artifacts. So this wont work for me. I am looking for something in the POM file for version upgrade and not from command line.